# How can I create an embedded Google Calendar widget that is logged in as a specified user?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I want to use Google Calendar's embed capabilities on a site but I want it to be viewed as if logged in by a specific user (we are using Google Apps for Business). I already know that a proxy service of some sort will have to be created but I'm not sure as to the steps that would be involved. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your users are already logged into Google (whether a normal Google account or a Google Apps account), you should just be able to use the Google-provided widget.

For a single calendar, you can use Google's tutorial [here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207). To get a normal view of every calendar that the user has access to (eg. the same things that the person sees at calendar.google.com) you should use the embed generator [here](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml&up_calendarFeeds=&up_calendarColors=&up_showDatepicker=1&up_showEmptyDays=0&up_showExpiredEvents=1&synd=open&w=320&h=447&title=__MSG_Google_Calendar__&lang=en&country=ALL&border=#ffffff%7C3px,1px%20solid%20#999999). This is an iGoogle widget, but Google allows you to style it and embed it on any site. The widget will automatically know who the user is, assuming they are logged in to Google.

Comment: We ended up figuring out the solution by creating a proxy script that logs in and outputs the same code as the embed.